# Ubuntu, block access to ports if deriving from a certain domain

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I'm currently using Nginx to host multiple websites on the same server. 
On this server, I host various apps which can be accessed via their port, for example:

- 0.0.0.0:6735
- http://domain1.com:6735
- http://domain2.com:6735

I don't want these ports to be accessible via the IP or domain2, I would like them to be requestable via only domain2.com, meaning requests such as these will be denied/allowed respectively:

- http://0.0.0.0:6735 **=>** DISALLOWED
- http://domain1.com:6735 **=>** DISALLOWED
- http://domain2.com:6735 **=>** ALLOWED

I've tried using ufw to block outside access to these domains and then enable proxy_passes pointing to localhost in settings however that doesn't work, and stops access altogether.

Comment: i am sorry my glassball tells me that you maybe use somekind of webserver  on anykind of os, with no information. pls Update, your question witj all what you did witj what tool etc

Comment: Impossible. There is no “domain” on the TCP level. Only IP and port number. Probably this apps shouldn’t be accessible via port from outside and should be proxied via nginx